# A question about an improper integral over an open set $A$. Why does $D$ need to be a closed set? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, definition

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

The following is the definition of an improper integral in this book.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the (extended) **integral** of $f$ over $A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense). More generally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on $A$, set $$f_{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\text{ and }f_{-}(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$ We say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense) if both $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ are; and in this case we set $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-},$$ where $\int_A$ denotes the extended integral throughout.

$D$ needs to be a bounded set since we define the (ordinary) integral of $f$ only over a bounded set.
The author wrote $D$ is a compact rectifiable subsets of $A$.
Why does $D$ need to be a closed set?

---

If $A=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$, $D:=A$ is a bounded rectifiable subset of $A$, but there is a continuous function $f$ on $A$ which is not bounded.

---

Can we define an improper integral over $A$ as follows?

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is non-negative on $A$, we define the (extended) **integral** of $f$ over $A$, denoted $\int_A f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_D f$, as $D$ ranges over all bounded rectifiable subsets of $A$ ***$\color{red}{\text{on which $f$ is bounded}}$***, provided this supremum exists. In this case, we say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense). More generally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on $A$, set $$f_{+}(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}\text{ and }f_{-}(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$ We say that $f$ is **integrable** over $A$ (in the extended sense) if both $f_{+}$ and $f_{-}$ are; and in this case we set $$\int_A f=\int_A f_{+}-\int_A f_{-},$$ where $\int_A$ denotes the extended integral throughout.

---

Can we modify the definition of an improper integral over $A$ in such a way $D$ doesn't need to be a closed set in a new definition?

Comment: I'm curious why it matters?